# htaccess rewrite not working as it should with www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm working on a CodeIgniter based application. My htacess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works great for the most part, and I can access controllers and methods like this:

```
http://example.com/controller/method/args
```

However, if it is appended with a www, like this

```
http://www.example.com/foo
```

It redirects to

```
http://example.com/index.php?foo
```

The page displayed is always the index page of my site.

I added the last pair of RewriteCond / RewriteRule simply to remove `www` if present.

I'm not quite sure how to get it to work the way I want, so that

```
http://www.example.com/foo
```

just redirects to

```
http://example.com/foo
```

**EDIT**

From my CI config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: Have you set `$config['index_page']` in `application/config/config.php`?

Comment: Yes. It is set to `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: Could the person who voted to close this, explain why?

Comment: the given conditions should work. as tested on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ the results were  http://i.imgur.com/1NCfv.png

Comment: Thanks for that link. Definitely a handy service. Perhaps the same rules don't work on my server due to a CI config.

Comment: Try placing your index.php to the end of the .htaccess file? That my solve your problems.

Comment: @StevenLu: Could you please explain that?

Comment: Your rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]` would be placed at the bottom. Order matters in this case due to your [L] flag.

Comment: @StevenLu: You, Sir, are the man! Moved the rule and the conditions to the bottom and it works as expected. If you post it as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Your welcome :) Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment.

Your rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]` should be placed at the bottom. Order matters in this case due to your `[L]` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Not really offering any more than Steven Lu here...but cleaned up your order to make a bit more sense

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# You don't really need the !-d (directory) flag here
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L] # Could put QSA in here too, but CI doesn't play too nice with query strings
```